# Loading images through URL not working in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am new in Xamarin forms .I was facing a problem to display an image.To fix that, I used four ways to display an image from the URL mentioned below.
I already changed HttpClient Implementation -> Managed and SSL/TLS changed into Native TLS 1.2+ but still facing the same problem. Please help me with this

Code-behind way

```
//1st way

img.Source = new Uri("https://aka.ms/campus.jpg");

//2nd way

ImageSource imageSource = new Uri("https://aka.ms/campus.jpg");

img1.Source = imageSource;
```

XAML

```
<Image x:Name="img1" />

<Image Source="https://aka.ms/campus.jpg" />

<Image>
    <Image.Source>
        <UriImageSource
            Uri="https://aka.ms/campus.jpg"
            CacheValidity="10:00:00.0" />
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

Options-> Android Options-> Advanced
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2xIU.png)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this code, actually all that you have tried should work...

Comment: the URL you are using is a redirect - try using the actual direct url instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just updating Xamarin forms to the newest version should solve this

Comment: No Problem.If it worked please accept my answer as that would help me too Thx